# RRAS on 2008R2 with routing and NAT

Tags: routing, nat, rras

I am looking for advise to set up a Windows 2008R2 based router with NAT functionality. My current network consists of a few subnets (reserved + real ip addresses), e.g. 10.20.30.0/24, 10.20.40.0/24 and 123.123.123.0/24. What I want to do is to connect all subnets so that they can communicate with each other while providing NAT to those reserved ip addresses (10.x.x.x) for Internet surfing. On the other hand, those with real ip addresses (123.123.123.x) should go online without the NAT. What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that Windows RRAS cannot do what I want, instead those real ip addresses will be connected via nat on RRAS. I give up finally and have a CentOS setup providing the routing/nat for the network.